# Session is set. But how to use the value of the session in an function?

Tags: jquery, session, session-state

My goal is to toggle (hide/show), a popup snippet. The design is that there are two folds in the popup snippet. If the user/client enters the email id on the first fold then it will be hidden and the next fold will be visible.

I planned to set the sessionStorage for this. The sessions are set, however I'm not sure how to use this session's value with an `if` condition such that if the session value is `x` then first fold is visible or if the session value is `y` then second fold is visible.

I expect to set session so that the last popup snippet where the user left or refreshed page must be visible.

I have tried using jQuery and Javascript, but unable to figure this out.

```html
<div id="firstFold">
  <p>This is the first fold</p>
</div>
<div id="secondFold">
  <p>This is the second fold</p>
</div>
```

```js
sessionStorage.setItem('x', 'firstFold');
sessionStorage.setItem('y', 'secondFold');

//Logic below.. please don't mind my code
if (the session of the page == firstFold) {
  $('#firstFold').show();
}
if (the session of the page == secondFold) {
  sessionStorage.removeItem("firstFold");
  $('#secondFold').show();
  $('#firstFold').hide();
}
```

```css
#firstFold {
  display: none;
}

#secondFold {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage

Comment: @Pete Thanks dude. I have referred but unable to implement the functions that I'd required.